# Atualizar UPDATE PHP

Tags: php, html

Boa noite estou tentando atualizar um cadastro de entrega de marmitas, eu clico no botão para atualizar e atualiza certinho no banco, porém quando vou atualizar novamente o mesmo pedido para entregue, a informação não é atualizada, só depois de um tempo do primeiro UPDATE que os dados são atualizados no banco... exemplo se eu atualizei  status para em transito agora, só depois de alguns minutos para atualizar o status para entregue. Alguém sabe me ajudar?

```
if($pedido > 0 && $status > 0){

 $atualizar = mysql_query("UPDATE pedidos SET id_status = '$status' WHERE 
 id_pedido= '$pedido'");

        if($atualizar){
            echo "atualizado, pedido $pedido e status $status";
        }else{
            echo "erro ".mysql_error();
        }
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <?php echo $linha["id_pedido"]; ?>
 </td>
 <td>
  <select name="status">    
   <option value='2'> Em Trânsito </option>
   <option value='4'> Entregue </option>
 </select>
 </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Depois de atualizar pela segunda vez, confira no banco. Existe muit apouca informação para analisar ai. De onde vem  a definição da variavel `$pedido`? Existe uma verificação e um `query` simples. Está certo se a verificação for verdadeira.

Comment: Isso ai ta estranho, se a pagina carrega normal, e você somente consegue alterar somente daqui alguns minutos, seria problema com loop talvez. Mais você perceberia. Tem que ver se ao setar o status, como essa informação e requisitada ao servidor.